# How can I expand a tensor in Libtorch? (The C++ version of PyTorch)

Tags: pytorch, torch, libtorch

How can I use LibTorch to expand a tensor of the shape 42, 358 into a shape of 10, 42, 358?

I know how to do this in PyTorch, (AKA Torch).
`torch.ones(42, 358).expand(10, -1, -1).shape`
returns
`torch.Size([10, 42, 358])`

In LibTorch I have a tensor of the same size I am trying to "expand" in the same way.

```
    auto expanded_state_batch = state_batch.expand(10, -1, -1);
```

I get the following error...

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘at::Tensor::expand(int, int, int)’
  335 |         auto expanded_state_batch = state_batch.expand(10, -1, -1);
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/core/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/function_hook.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/cpp_hook.h:2,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:6,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/multiv_normal.cpp:2:
/home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:2372:19: note: candidate: ‘at::Tensor at::Tensor::expand(at::IntArrayRef, bool) const’
 2372 | inline at::Tensor Tensor::expand(at::IntArrayRef size, bool implicit) const {
      |                   ^~~~~~
/home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:2372:19: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
```

It says that `.expand` only takes two integers but three were given. I've tried a few combinations and I always get an error.
Exactly what I'm doing here is concatenating the 42, 385 tensor ten times into a new tensor. I could do this in a loop with `torch::cat`, but this would be uglier.

Answer (score 1):

`at::expand` expects an `at::IntArrayRef` the compiler tells you. Hence you want to write something like

```
auto expanded_state_batch = state_batch.expand({10, -1, -1});
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, you left `.expand` off the end of `state_batch`. If you want to fix it I'll give you the green check.

Comment: I'm going to answer this myself and give myself the green check in a day or two if you don't want to make the edit. Add `.expand` to the end of `state_batch`